# How to solve "Not unique table/alias"? (node, sequelize)

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am implementing a comment service using 'express' and 'sequelize' modules. This comment service supports 'reply'. The model has 'user' and 'comment'.

```
Comment.hasMany(Comment, {foreignKey: {name: 'parent_comment', allowNull: true}, as: 'reply'});
Comment.belongsTo(Comment, {foreignKey: {name: 'parent_comment', allowNull: true}, as: 'parent'});
User.hasMany(Comment, {foreignKey: {allowNull: false}, onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
Comment.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: {allowNull: false}, onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
```

I want to join the user by bringing in the "reply" part of the comment. like below...

```
[
     {
          somedata...,
          writer: { // User model
               userdata....
          },
          reply: [
               {
                    somedata....
                    writer: { // User model
                         userdata....
                    }
               },
               ....
          ]
     },
     ....
]
```

However, as a result, an error occurs while outputting a message of 'Not unique table/alias'. Erase the marked 'this line' part and bring it normally, but it's not the desired result. code like this,

```
const c = await Comment.findAll({
        include: [
               {
                    model: User
               },
               {
                    model: Comment,
                    include: [{ model: User}]     //// this line!
               },
        ]
});
```

How can I get the results I want? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Comment` has 2 relationships with `Comment` (of course with aliases) you always need to indicate a desired alias in queries when you need to include `Comment` in `Comment`:

```js
const c = await Comment.findAll({
        include: [
               {
                    model: User
               },
               {
                    model: Comment,
                    as: 'reply', // or as: 'parent' depending on your goal
                    include: [{ model: User}]
               },
        ]
});
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!! It's been solved.